# How to set interval option for timeslider with same min and maxdate using Ol-ext:Timeline control?

Tags: openlayers, timeslider

I am trying to create a timeslider with Ol-extension timeline similiar to https://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/storymap/map.control.timequake.html. All the sample codes have different min and maxDate with graduation option as day. The following code works

```
var tline = new ol.control.Timeline({
    graduation:'day',
    minDate: new Date('2020/5/1'),
    maxDate: new Date('2020/5/10')
  });
  map.addControl (tline);
```

However I need to create a timeslider with a 15 minute interval on a single day. I used the interval property  but nothing works. How to fix this?

```
 var tline = new ol.control.Timeline({
    interval:'15mn',
    minDate: new Date('2020/5/1'),
    maxDate: new Date('2020/5/1')
  });
  map.addControl (tline);
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add an example of your data your are using for timeline.

Comment: Have you tried to set `maxDate` to the next day instead of the same date? So in your example set it to `maxDate: new Date('2020/5/2')`